# Android EventListeners

Tags: android, event-listener, oncreate

I am trying to figure out why I can't access the `setOnClickListener()` outside the `onCreate()` method.

The following code snippet is placed below the `onCreate()` method.

```
        TextView numbers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NumbersActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I am trying to set EventListener to a `TextView`, but `setOnClickListener` appears in a red line. Why is this happening? I mean if I place the code snippet inside the `onCreate()` method it's working. Why I can't access the `setOnClickListener` from outside?

Comment: Why dont you implement View.OnclickListner to your activity and just set numbers.setOnClickListner(this) and override the interface method ?

Comment: show your code when placed outside onCreate()

Answer (score 1):

You can't access view out side its bounded area here `onCreate()` method's bound. If you want that then you have to inflate the view by `layout-inflater`.

Answer (score 0):

Because those are one of the programming language rules. Outside of a method or function you can declare static blocks, declare other functions or make assignment. `setOnClickListener` is a method which accepts as an argument `interface` and looks something like this:

```
public interface OnClickListener {
    void onClick(View v);
}
```

And actually there are couple implementations. One of them you have used above in example, second one is to `implement View.OnClickListener` interface and override method `onClick(View view)` now you can subscribe your views to this interface `numbers.setOnClickListener(this)` and if you have more than one view subscribed you can distinguish between them inside `onClick(View view)` by checking for `id` like:

```
public void onClick(View view){
   switch(view.getId()){
     case R.id.numbers:
     break;
 }
}
```

And there is one more implementation which would look like this:

```
public OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

  }
};
```

Now you can use: `numbers.setOnClickListener(onClick)`